# How can I get cookies in django template without request?

Tags: django, cookies, django-templates, django-views

I have a form. Need the after its send to the server the page refresh and shown message "*Thanx for review*". I'm us cookies for it, but I can't to get cookies in `template`

```
def post(self, request, slug):
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    response = HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
    response.set_cookie('review_added', 'yes')
    return response
```

**Update**

I solved the problem this way, but it seems to me this is bad practice.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context['review_added'] = self.request.COOKIES.get('review_added')
    return context
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. A cookie has nothing to do with a template. It's a HTTP header that you set in the response headers telling the browser to send the same cookie back for every subsequent request. You read the cookie in the `request` object (in a view). So basically there's nothing wrong with your code. But you might want to delete the cookie after it was used, since it will stay there indefinitely otherwise.

Comment: Note that Django has a [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/messages/) that allows you to set a message that will be rendered in the next request. Just do `messages.success(request, 'Thanks for review.')` and if you use [`messages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages) in your template, it will display.

Comment: But I need to store value in cookies.

Comment: Updated my first comment.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thnx for help.

Comment: Also remember that anyone can change/tamper their cookies very easily, so don't use that as a security measure to avoid multiple reviews or something like that. Not sure why you say you "need to store value in cookies".

Comment: @dirkgroten 
We have a form (fake), which is not saved to the database. simply, when the user sends it, we write in cookies that he submitted the form and then simply hide this form each time the page is loaded (of course, if the user clears the cookies, he will see it again, but this implementation suits everyone now).